# Best way to control user interface

Tags: c++, linux

What is the best way to control the user interface on linux using C++ program.
I need to be able to move the mouse, enter text, and view the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Xlib....
you can call things like Warp pointer.
The documentation is here
http://tronche.com/gui/x/ with some example programs.

EDIT:
http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/input/

Answer (score 0):

To control mouse/keyboard input you should just take a look at xdotool, an open source binary that allows control of the X11 inputs: http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/#id54155

You can freely reuse their code as long as you are ok with the license.

For grabbing screenshots of windows (which is what I think you want to do) the best combination I found under linux is a combination of X11 window managing functions (such as get window by title) and imlib2.